# Showing comparison across groups in tooltip Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard that lets users compare a company selected from a drop down menu (Company A) to another company chosen from another drop down menu (Company B). This then displays stacked bar charts (5 categories) by year. I want to build a tooltip so that when the user hovers over one of the 5 categories in either set of bar charts, it shows a comparison of that category between Company A and Company B. Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to do this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous answer showed a different approach for the problem without using too many workarounds. This answer will try to give exactly what has been asked.

First thing to understand is that **you can't have the values for two different companies if you're filtering to show only one company**. That means you'll need to circumvent this by filtering directly on the field.

### Step 1: Create the new parameters that will be used as filters.

You want to create two parameters called "Company 1" and "Company 2" that will be used in each view to filter the company on the graphic.

[image: Parameter]

### Step 2: Create the new measures with the filter directly in the field.

Now you should create two new measures from your main measure, each one filtering one of the companies accordingly to the parameter, *e.g. Sales Company 1 and Sales Company 2*.

[image: Calculated field with parameter]

### Step 3: Create a field with the variation and add it at the tooltip mark.

Simply enough, you want a calculated field with the difference between them:

```
SUM([Sales C1]) - SUM([Sales C2])
```

### Step 4: Update the views and dashboard

Change the measure in each of the views for their following specific measure field, **and remove the Company filter**. And in the dashboard, substitute your usual filters to the parameter (which will be used to filter both views).

[image]

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. You are a hero astro, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By assuming you have a dashboard with two views, you'll be filtering the [Company] in both of these views, making the value of *another company* not available to be shown at the tooltip.

If you're not using it yet, you could try a new approach and see the variance between companies by using the **Color mark**. By adding the [Company] as color, you could turn the **Stack Marks** off and add the second company in the filter to be able to *visualize* the difference.

[image: Comparing companies with Stack Marks off]

Comment: Wow Astro you are everywhere! This is the same visualization that I was working on in the other post that you answered. Do you have any suggestions on how to build the tooltip without changing the colors? I already use color for the stacked bar chart.